# Goodness of fit p-value question

Tags: statistics

I am currently checking whether my model of classification fits the the data: I used goodness of fit to calculate p-value and use 5% level of significance, let's consider:

Null Hypothesis: the model well classify the data

Alternate Hypothesis: otherwise

In this type of testing, do we expect p-value > 0.05 to accept the null hypothesis, because this sounds weird since most research expect p-value to be < 0.05. Could anyone explain me about this problem?

Your help is really appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As with any other hypothesis test, a p-value $< 0.05$ would tell us to accept the *alternate* hypothesis, while a p-value $> 0.05$ would tell us not to reject the null.

A low p-value would mean that the observed distribution of the data would be unlikely if your model was correct; therefore we would accept the alternate hypothesis that the model doesn't fit the data.

Comment: Therefore, in this type of problem, do we need p > 0.05 to show that the model fit?

Comment: You would need $p>0.05$ to not reject the model.  You are never really proving that the model fits, because you never prove the null hypothesis.  Rather, the high p-value would mean that the model could be accurate.

Comment: @browngreen : Please: look at my edits in the following link. Why used MathJax at all if you neglect to use most of the features that would have helped? Setting things in display rather than inline, using subscripts were appropriate, using \operatorname where appropriate, and getting rid of the asterisk for ordinary multiplication (which is a workaround for use when you're limited to the characters on the keyboard). https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2361828/revisions